# How to distribute turtles similar to a population distributed across the patches

Tags: netlogo

[image]

I have a model in which a population is normally distributed across the patches. I used the following code to do that:

```
ask patches [
let x1 (pxcor - mean1) / sd-pop1
let y1 (pycor - mean2) / sd-pop1
set popualation ( (pop1) * exp (-0.5 * ( x1 ^ 2 + y1 ^ 2)) / (2 * pi * sd-pop1 ^ 2))
]
```

I want to distribute 10 turtles in a similar manner. In the attached image just as how the major chunk of the population is distributed across the patches close to the center of the grid space. Similarly of the 10 turtles to be created, i want a major chunk to be randomly spread across the population rich patches and a few which are spread on the periphery.

```
to setup-parties
  create-parties Num-of-parties
  let sp sqrt((((sd-pop1 ^ 2) * (pop1 - 1)) + ((sd-pop2 ^ 2) * (pop2 - 1))) / (pop1 + pop2 - 2))
  ask parties [
    ifelse (pop2 > 0) [ set heading random-float 360 jump random-float sp ] [ set heading random-float 360 jump random-float sd-pop1 ]
    set size 3
    set color random 130
    set label who + 1
    set label-color red
    set my-old-size 1
    set shape "default"
    set old-x xcor
    set old-y ycor
    update-rule
    ]

end
```

Comment: I tried the extension and code JenB suggested and they work. But i want the turtles to be created as a breed and not normal turtles.

Comment: You need to use [`sprout-<breeds>`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sprout) instead of just `sprout`. In you case, that would be `sprout-parties`.

Comment: @NicolasPayette: Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `rnd` extension for this and select 10 patches (weighted by population) to sprout a turtle. Something like `ask rnd:weighted-n-of 10 patches [ population ] [ sprout 1 ]`. You will also need `extensions [rnd]` at the top of your code if you use this method.

Comment: ask rnd:weighted-n-of  10 [ population ] [sprout 1] is throwing an error stating that it "expected a list of block rather than an agentset". If i try rnd:weighted-n-of-list then its throwing an error saying "Expected a constant"

Comment: have amended the example (still not tested). Have you looked at the documentation for the rnd extension?